# what is the use of count— in the programm?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and cant understand the use of "count" in this program.I have to print prime numbers between a certain range which would be entered by the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaProgram
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int start, end, i, j, count=0;



        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the Range :\n");

        System.out.print("Enter Starting Number : ");
        start = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Ending Number : ");
        end = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Prime Numbers Between " + start + " and " +end+ " is :\n");
        for(i=start; i<=end; i++)
        {
            count = 0;
            for(j=2; j<i; j++)
            {
                if(i%j == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: count is used to get the number of divisors of the number. If count is 0, it means number is prime. If we do not need the number ofn divisors in program we can replace it with boolean as well.

Answer (score 1):

`count` is used here as an indicator. When it's `0`, the number is prime. It can be replaced by a `boolean`:

```
    boolean prime = true;
    ...
    for(i=start; i<=end; i++) {
        prime = true;
        for(j=2; j<i; j++) {
            if(i%j == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is used as a reference to keep track of how many times a number is divided, if the divisor number is 0 then the algorithm knows that the number is a prime